# Xamarin.Forms "App has stopped working" on android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

So I encounterd this error just now and this causes my android application not to work on the device. Whenever I debug my application for android it crashes for some reasont. . As a new user to Xamarin I'm clueless.

Here is the error I`m getting:

```
[art] Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
[ContextImpl] Unable to create files subdir /data/data/com.comhuis.saleskicker.sales_kicker/cache
[ContextImpl] Unable to create files subdir /data/data/com.comhuis.saleskicker.sales_kicker/files
[AndroidRuntime] Shutting down VM
[AndroidRuntime] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[AndroidRuntime] Process: com.comhuis.saleskicker.sales_kicker, PID: 5035
[AndroidRuntime] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider mono.MonoRuntimeProvider: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5015)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4607)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4547)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:148)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
[AndroidRuntime]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
[AndroidRuntime]    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
[AndroidRuntime] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoPackageManager.LoadApplication(MonoPackageManager.java:27)
[AndroidRuntime]    at mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.attachInfo(MonoRuntimeProvider.java:42)
[AndroidRuntime]    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5012)
[AndroidRuntime]    ... 11 more
[Process] Sending signal. PID: 5035 SIG: 9
```

I haven't really got something special in my project. I can't upload a screenshot of my solution just yet but I`ll try and describe it:

My solution exists out of **SalesKicker** and **SalesKicker.Droid**. **SalesKicker** has 3 files **MainPage.Xaml MainPage.Xaml.cs SalesKicker.cs**.
and **SalesKicker.Droid** contains the usual stuff plus 1 image called delogo.png which I`m using as appicon. This is my MainActivity.cs code:

```
namespace SalesKicker.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = @"Sales Kicker", Icon = "@drawable/delogo", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity :     global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        Xamarin.Insights.Initialize (global::SalesKicker.Droid.XamarinInsights.ApiKey, this);
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        LoadApplication (new App ());
    }
}
```

I've also  been trying to set some breakpoints. I've tried it on every line and still got the same error over and over again. I also tried to set my "Target Version" to Lollipop 5.0, which is the current software version on my LG G3, and it didn't really have any effect. And I also have every single Android SDK installed. Since I'm quite new to Xamarin I'm clueless. Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, the exception is really clear, you're trying to get the path from a File object which is null (you or a component you use), my bet is a component is trying to write to the SD card and the G3 has another mapping for external/internal storage thus it can't be created or found. Try it on the emulator.

Comment: Ah I see, but how can I change the writing path to the Device's internal storage?

Comment: Is your code the one throwing the exception or is it from a component? If it's form a component, ask to the developer who created it, if it's your code, then there are some solutions like testing different paths to check where it's mapped, use the SDK monitor app and examine your device's file system.

Comment: It's my code, where can I find this SDK monitor?

Comment: And I don't actually save images yet, I'm only using it as an app icon

Comment: It's the Android SDK, on the Tools folder you have a file called "monitor.bat"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it after looking at another thread: [Why does my Xamarin Android application suddenly require external storage permissions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19850198/why-does-my-xamarin-android-application-suddenly-require-external-storage-permis)

I just had to go to: AndroidManifest.xml and set 'Install location' to **internalOnly**. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create this folder on your android device if you can.

```
/data/data/{your.apps.package.name}
```

Otherwise, uninstall your app then re-install it again.

You may noticed that the exception is rise by "File.getAbsolutePath()".

After decompile my app's `.apk` package, i found this is cause by `getFilesDir()` returning `null`.

```
// MonoPackageManager.java
String str1 = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();  // <- Exception
String str2 = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
```